# Execute cmd prompt commands using PHP

Tags: php, cmd

I just need to check if Sql Loader is installed in my PHP server or no. And I need this to be done using PHP file/code.

What I have tried

```
This worked in my Command Prompt
C:>sqlldr 

Unable to to get the same done using PHP
shell_exec('sqlldr')
```

Comment: May be you can try to check if .exe file is exists?

Comment: Like how ? I need to check with PHP application only

Comment: To get the error output (if any) use the suggestion here; http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#88621

Comment: can you let us know the exact path to `sqlldr` ? You need to set the environment variable of windows. or you need to specify the full path directly in `shell_exec('C:\path\to\sqlldr.exe')`. And you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php to set the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: This is an environment variable just like 'javac', so if I type sqlldr anywhere in the command line it must display the help manual

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run shell script file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507840/unable-to-run-shell-script-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'C:\sqlldr.exe'; //use correct path to your .exe file. Be careful with slashes
if(file_exists($path))
  //do smth;
```

Comment: what is the exact location of `sqlldr` ? Put the correct path instead of `C:\sqlldr.exe`

Comment: sqlldr is SQL Loader.