# Unable to run shell script file using PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, sh

Hi I am unable to run the .sh file using my php code.

```
 Files:  index.php and .sh files are in the same directory.
```

What I have tried:

```
 echo shell_exec('sh shell_file.sh'); //Did not execute
 echo shell_exec('shell_file.sh'); //Did not execute
 echo exec('shell_file.sh'); //Did not execute
```

But when I run the shell_file.sh file manually it does execute.

Comment: why didn't you try `exec('sh shell_file.sh');`?

Comment: does www-data (or whoever who runs actual php script) user have permissions to run the sh script?

Comment: Are you really in the directory you think you are? `shell_exec('pwd');`. Are you allowed to execute it ``shell_exec('whoami');``

Comment: @cmorrissey Tried that now , still not working

Comment: @SergeiKovalenko Yes I am having permissions to run the sh script

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes I am able to execute     shell_exec('whoami');  and it returns apache

Comment: What does `ls -l shell_file.sh` output

Comment: It gives as -r--rwxr--+ 1 usr usr 155 May 28 08:59 shell_file.sh

Comment: chmod the file apache (as user and group) doesn't have execute right

Comment: So the permissions are wrong.  The `apache` use needs executable permissions. Or you can make the script executable by anyone by running `chmod o+x shell_file.sh`

Comment: @dan08 you mean *chmod o+x shell_file.sh*

Comment: @donald123 Change in Permission are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

What you need to do is call the file with a program. Call it with bash or sh as suggested in the comment:

```
echo shell_exec('sh /shell_file.sh');
```

Another option could be:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('/shell_file.sh');
echo shell_exec($contents);
```

I think the first option would be better however.

Comment: I am nt getting any errors . Also I have removed / and tried

Comment: Nope I havent tried. The only thing I am confused is as to why I am nt getting any errors